# Swift Cast to Generic Type with Constraint

Tags: swift, generics, types, casting

I am using Swift 3 with [constrained generics](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/GenericParametersAndArguments.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH37-XID_775) (i.e. a `where` clause). I have a problem when I am trying to do generic type casting. Here is a simplified example of the problem:

```
func jsonToObj<T:DomainResource>(jsonStr: String) -> [T:DomainResource] {
    let json = JSON(parseJSON: jsonStr).dictionaryObject
    let bundle = SMART.Bundle(json: json)

    let result = bundle.entry?.map() {
        return $0.resource as! T
    }

    return result!
}
```

My problem is when I return from the method, the compiler complains its cannot convert type `[T]` to type `[T:DomainResource]`. If I remove the `DomainResource` constraint from the generic, it compiles and runs just fine.

That's not what I want, so, I tried this:

```
let result = bundle.entry?.map() {
    return $0.resource as! T:DomainResource
}
```

Swift doesn't seem to know what that means. Any idea on how to work around this problem? I'd like to not just cast them all to `DomainResource` objects, if possible.

Comment: What do you mean by removing the constraint isn't what you want? `[T:DomainResource]` isn't an array of `T` constrained to `DomainResource` – it's a *dictionary*. You just want `[T]`. The placeholder `T` is still constrained to `DomainResource` in the placeholder declaration. Although the force cast to `T` in the `map(_:)` still looks a bit iffy – are you sure it can never fail (for *any* concrete type of `T`)?

Comment: This `[T: DomainResource]` is a wrong return type. You are returning a dictionary instead of just `T`.

Comment: Right, I was returning a dictionary. That makes sense. Also, yes, we are mapping our data against a standard that is why the `as!` always works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote this function signature:

```
func jsonToObj<T:DomainResource>(jsonStr: String) -> [T:DomainResource]
```

This says that the `jsonToObj(jsonStr:)` method returns a dictionary whose keys are of type `T` and whose values are of type `DomainResource`. It looks like you just want to write this function signature:

```
func jsonToObj<T:DomainResource>(jsonStr: String) -> [T]
```

Comment: That's it. Thank you.